# How to Configure Pattern for DateFormat's getDateInstance()

Tags: java

Is there any away to configure the pattern for String values returned by DateFormat's `getDateInstance()`, for each style - SHORT, MEDIUM, LONG, and FULL?

For example, `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.US)` will always return a value something like Jan 12, 1952. How can I have this return 1952, Jan 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize your own date format using [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
    String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy, MMM dd").format(new Date(52, 0, 12)); 
    System.out.println(formatted); //prints "1952, Jan 12"
```

**Edit**

Ok if you are trying to override for just some specific locales, you can configure your own DateFormatProvider:

```
class CustomDateFormatProvider extends DateFormatProvider {
    public DateFormat getDateInstance(int style, Locale locale) {
        if ( style == DateFormat.MEDIUM && Locale.US.equals(locale) ) {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy, MMM dd");
        }
        //else do default behaviour
    }

    //...
}
```

This can be installed using the Java Extension Mechanism.  See [LocaleServiceProvider](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html).

If this isn't what you're looking for you should add some actual requirements to your question.  I addressed the question you asked, but it seems there's a question you didn't ask for which you're still waiting for an answer.

But obviously this will only alter ones that you specifically override.

Comment: Then, you would be using a fixed format for all locales. I'm looking for a solution to customize date formats while supporting internationalization.

Comment: @Tom: Then why don't you stick with what the locale provides?  You're basically saying you don't want to localize according to standards, but you still want to localize?  Can't have it both ways.  Of course you could always make a utility method to do something custom based on the locale.

Comment: The "standard formats" are what the Java specification decided and often not consistent with the system running the Java application. I want to support localization the way standard Java applications do(i.e. DateFormat's getDateInstance()), but want to customize actual values(i.e. pattern). Using a ResourceBundle is a standard way of localizing a Java application, but each application is free to customize a ResourceBundle.

Comment: Yeah, I was lookin for something like this, but I'm using Java 5. Looks like LocaleServiceProvider was added to Java 6.

Comment: @Tom: You can create your own factory and make all of your code that requests a DateFormat go through that.  This should work for most cases; the only stuff that won't work is when the Java libraries themselves request a DateFormat in the background.